# Vertical Centering with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason centering items in this Bootstrap example doesn't seem to be working the way that it normally would with CSS using the table/table-cell method of:

```
<div class="parent" style="display:table">  
  <div class="child" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle>
    <h1>This is the lockup to be centered</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Bootstrap version of something I'm working on is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
        <section class="hero--section col-lg-12">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center hero--content">
            <h1>Bore'em Ipsum</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis totam numquam id quidem eligendi temporibus ullam cupiditate, assumenda, qui eaque deserunt libero, vitae sed expedita dolores laborum iusto accusamus facere.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima quam eveniet dolorem sapiente reiciendis dolorum sit nam debitis odio optio, dignissimos, dolor nulla rerum earum aliquid molestias! Culpa, odit, quo!</p>
            <p><a class="" href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/20x20" alt=""></a></p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.container {
  background:lavender;
  display:block;
}

.hero--section {
  display:table;
    height:535px;
}

.hero--content {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Example of issue here:
http://codepen.io/pdnellius/pen/bEPXyG.

Anyone have an idea what I'm missing here? This is my goto method for vertical centering. I know I could probably use transform to solve this. But I'd like to know the 'why' behind why this isn't working. Is something being overridden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is floating your table and table cell elements with `float: left` on both.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.hero--content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: justify;
    float: none; /* NEW */
}
```

---

If the floats are essential to your layout, then try another centering solution. Here's a flex alternative:

```
.hero--section {
    display: flex;
    height: 535px;
}

.hero--content {
    margin: auto; 
 }
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxXBxG)

In a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers), floats are ignored.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More browser compatibility details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Comment: Hm, so I can do that... but then I lose my grid. Not sure this is optimal.

Comment: Well that's the source of your problem. I'll post an alternative for your vertical centering.